# Retrieve the attribute value from the HTML tag using python beautiful soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve only the attribute values from the all FONT tags from an HTML page. The HTML content(for one of the many FONT tags) is as below:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">&#546;</td>
        <td>
            <a href="space.xml" target="Dest">
                <FONT COLOR="#0000FF">Start</FONT>
            </a>
        </td>
</tr>
```

I want to retrieve the FONT COLOR value and add it to a list, post that I want to check if the value is #0000FF or #FF0000. But when trying to retrieve only the value , it is fetching the entire tag . My code snippet look like this:

```
trs = soup_file.select("[COLOR]")
print(trs)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If so, please mark any of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
soup_file = BeautifulSoup(above_html_string, "html.parser")
color = soup_file.find("font").attrs["color"]
```

will give you

```
'#0000FF'
```